# Notifications opening activities and the back button? Restricting to one instance?

Tags: android

There's a situation I have that's related to the Activity stack but I'm new enough to Android dev to not now how to respond to it.

I have an application that works like a stopwatch. When you start it, an ongoing notification goes in the notification tray and remains ongoing until you stop the stopwatch. I've noticed that if my stopwatch is running in the foreground, and I touch the notification, it creates a new instance of my stopwatch's activity and slides the old one off screen. This creates problems with the back button (you press back and the new instance goes away to reveal the old instance). It makes sense why this happens, but I don't want it to happen like this. What can I do to prevent multiple instances of my application from running?

Comment: You should employ the DRY principle when asking a question. I don't think there is a need to put "[Android]" in your question, when you tag it with the android tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What can I do to prevent multiple instances of my application from running?

In your `Intent` you use with the `PendingIntent` for the `Notification`, add `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);` or `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);`, whichever behavior fits your needs better.

Comment: What's the difference in their behavior?

Comment: @Corey Ogburn: If you have several activities, the `CLEAR_TOP` variant will wip the task history, leaving the user only with the activity triggered by the `Notification`. The `REORDER` variant simply pulls the existing activity to the foreground, leaving any other activities still in the task history. The docs for those flags have more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could also disable the back button. Not as elegant as CommonsWare solution but nothing wrong with some options!

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```